# How the first array entry differs from the second

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, console-application

I can not understand the difference between the declaration with array initialization in the first case and the second

```
int[] array = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] secondArray = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

They seem to do the same thing, maybe they work differently?

Comment: both are same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is no difference in the result between the two show lines shown:

```
int[] array = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] secondArray = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

However, there are practical differences between `new int[n] {...}`  syntax and `{...}`:

1. Implicit type is not available for the alternative array initialiser:

   ```
   var a1 = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 }; // OK
   var a2 = { 1, 2, 3 }; // Error: Cannot initialize an implicitly-typed variable with an array initializer

   // BTW. You can omit the size
   var a3 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }; // OK
   ```
2. With the alternative syntax you cannot specify the size, it's always inferred.

   ```
   var a1 = new int[100]; // Array with 100 elements (all 0)
   int[] a2 = { }; // Array with no elements
   ```

---

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the compiled code between the two lines.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is just a shortcut. Both statements have the same result. The shorter variant just wasn't available in early versions of C#.

Answer (score 0):

The first one uses 3 as a array size explictly, the 2nd one size is inferred.
This might be work if you dont want to initialize the values.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between this two [array initialization syntaxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays#array-initialization) in terms how they will be translated by the compiler into IL (you can play with it at [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQOwDtgBtAXQAIBDAJyooE8yBeM/AUwHcyDiBmcgbzLooZVCJ5kAvgG48hUmQDOrAMYB7fDACCNekzKDho8VNnZuC4AAswVbbobM2nCwKEixZCTJzJ0ATgAKAEppIA=)) and it is the same as the following one:

```cs
int[] thirdArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

The only difference comes when you are using those with already declared variable, i.e. you can use 1st and 3rd to assign new value to existing array variable but not the second one:

```cs
int[] arr;
arr = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };   // works
// arr = { 1, 2, 3 };           // won't compile
arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };    // works
```